# How to traverse a lookup field to find if a value exists or not

Tags: apex, lookup

I have a lookup field on my contact object named "ALO" and it is a restrictive lookup field as in it only accepts few values.I want to assign it the value stored in "account owner" field on the account object but here is the problem.

If the "account owner" value is the legitimate value for ALO lookup field i.e if the value exists as one of the options in ALO lookup field, only then it gets assigned otherwise if the value does not exist in the ALO field then it should set the field to null. However, I am confused how do I traverse the ALO lookup field to find out if the account owner value is an acceptable value for ALO lookup field?

Here is my code:

```
public Account acc {get; set;}

// I am retrieving the account object here and the account owner 
acc = [
       SELECT Id, OwnerId
       FROM Account
       WHERE Id =: contact.AccountId
      ];

// This is the line where I am stuck. Here I am trying to check if account owner value exists as one of the options in ALO lookup field                   
List<User> user= [SELECT ALO__c FROM contact where ALO =:acc.OwnerId];

if (user.size() == 1) 
{
    contact.ALO__c = acc.OwnerId;
}
else
{
    contact.ALO__c= null;
}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? For one, in your SOQL query on Contact, you are not specifying the full api name for your ALO field. Additionally you are putting a list of Contacts into a list of Users. The full line should be `List<Contact> user= [SELECT ALO__c FROM contact where ALO__c =:acc.OwnerId];`.

Comment: so ALO is a lookup field to user but it itself is on contact object. And acc.OwnerId is also a user. I don't actually know how to write that statement. I don't think the above statement can traverse the ALO lookup field values and find out if account owner value exists there.

Comment: If I understand the requirements and your code correctly, you don't actually need to query at all because you already have a reference to a contact. You can simply check `if(contact.ALO__c == acc.OwnerId) { //logic here }`

Comment: no contact.ALO field would be null initially. contact is a particular Contact record in my above code. ALO lookup field is a restricted field with some defined values. So before I insert acc.owner value in ALO, I want to check if it is actually a legitimate value for ALO. So I need help with the part where I actually fetch all the values that can be assigned to ALO, check if acc.owner is one of those values. If yes, then only assign acc.owner value to ALO otherwise set ALO to null.

Comment: I have also made changes to my question to clarify it. Let me know if you need some more information.

Comment: When you say *ALO lookup field is a restricted field with some defined values* -- how have you defined those values?